# nHibernate not bubbling error

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

I'm sure this was working and has now stopped and I can't work out why. My classes are too complex to post, but I made a simple class to test and it's still happening.

I created a class "abc" which has a couple of properties which are not null in the database. I created an instance of the class and purposefully leave a property null so that it will throw in an error. In the output window, the error is shown as

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException' occurred in NHibernate.DLL

But the exception is not bubbling up to my code and runs through with no issue. The row is not in the database, and if I copy the SQL from SQL profiler I get the correct error of "cannot insert null into column...."

The problem is that I'm creating a couple of objects within a transaction and if one fails I expect an error to be thrown so that I can rollback all, but since the errors are not bubbling, I can't catch them, so I can't rollback.

The below isnt actually code but to demonstrate what I mean:

```
using (NHibernate.ITransaction tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        // Should Fail
        ABC a1 = new ABC();
        a1.prop1 = "1234";
        Session.SaveOrUpdate(a1);

        // Should Save
        ABC a2 = new ABC();
        a2.prop1 = "1234";
        a2.prop2 = "1234";
        Session.SaveOrUpdate(a2);

        // Should Fail
        ABC a3 = new ABC();
        Session.SaveOrUpdate(a3);

        tx.Commit()

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tx.Rollback()
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

In the above objects `a1` and `a3` should throw errors (and do as seen in the output window) as the inserts fail, but it doesn't get caught by the `catch {}` statement, it just steps through and so `tx.commit` runs and `a2` is persisted to the database (which `shouldn't` happen).

Any Ideas?
Ty.

Comment: Not related to the question ... but you should just `throw`, instead of `throw ex`. I think it keeps the original stack trace.

Comment: Yep, the above isnt actual code, was from my head. I log the error and then pass it off to a handler rather than re-throwing. Point is that it doesnt even get there and it should.

Comment: how do you handle NHibernateSession? Nhibernate version?

Comment: Do you have any customer NHibernate event listener, interceptor, or similar?

Comment: As pointed by @OskarBerggren, I would first look at custom handlers, then ensure that each call to Session does not instantiate a new Session, then, does it make a difference if you replace all SaveOrUpdate with Save, then try to flush after each Save/SaveOrUpdate

Comment: If I were you, I would just take NH code, compile it with debug configuration, and then debug the whole thing. It's sometimes the easiest way to find a problem. If it really is something wrong in NH, log a bug.

Comment: @OskarBerggren: Thanks, it was a nHibernate event listener (OnPostInsert, OnPostUpdate) that was consuming the error and not rethrowing. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. User error again. Does anyone know why the VS debugger wasnt breaking on the exception, it does for other code?

Comment: @Tyrone Have you enabled break-when-thrown in Debug->Exceptions?

Comment: @Tyrone Please also add the fix as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `Session.Close()` after transaction commit.

Lazy loading and NHibernate cache sometimes have strange behavior.

Comment: By default, Commit() will cause flushing to occur, and if it does need to be called explicitly, it should be _before_ the commit.

Comment: @OskarBerggren i don't think it is a good idea to flush the connection before committing the transaction...

Comment: Perhaps we're misinterpreting each other, but my point is that usually you should not call Flush() at all, since it will already be done by the call to Commit(). However, if you do have changed the default settings, I think you most definitely want to call Flush() before Commit(), not after, because otherwise any actual changes will not be part of the transaction.

Comment: you are right i was thinking about Session.Close and not Session.Flush